# Google Play Console - How To Inform If My App Contains Ads

Tags: android, ads, release, google-play-console

I'm having a problem setting up my first app for release. I need to inform Play Console whether my app contains ads or not, but on that section, there's simply no option to click. Nothing.

[Screenshot of the App Content Ads Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw5qB.png)

I don't know what am I doing wrong. If I need to put some information in other places before coming to this part, or if that is a bug - and if it's a bug, if it is affecting other people as well. Or am I missing something completely?

**EDIT: I found the problem: I had an AdBlock turned on. When I turned it off the page loaded correctly and I was able to finish the setup.**

Answer (score 6):

As of 2021 this option has been moved to the **Policy section** in the console and no longer the [image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: In store management click on App content]

In your play console go to the `store presence` then click on `App  content` where you can set whether your app contains Ads or not.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but, as you can see on my screenshot, when I enter the App content page the options to click do not appear.

Comment: I found the problem: I had an AdBlock turned on. When I turned it off the page loaded correctly and I was able to finish the setup.